# Is there a function in Zend Framework to handle file uploads?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

Zend Framework makes development a lot easier; for instance there is a getPost function from the Zend_Http that handles POST parameters.

Is there anything similar to handle file uploads? I can access $_FILES directly, but I would rather use a built in function to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Zend_Form_Element_File, it has very similar functionality as Zend_File_Transfer and it works without any problems.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file

Answer (score 1):

You can do file uploads with Zend_Form. Tutorial [here](http://akrabat.com/2008/04/07/simple-zend_form-file-upload-example/).

Answer (score 1):

Read about [`Zend_File_Transfer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction).  Does that do what you need?

Comment: I just tried that, and to my surprise it throws an exception saying 'Implementation in Progress'. Though the documentation seems complete?

Comment: Sounds like you should use Zend_Form_Element_File as @da5id and @harvejs have suggested.